# Desktop Java Server Php Client Socket between Server and Computer ( with external IP )

Tags: java, sockets

I have a PHP Script, and a Java Client. I want the Php Script to send Messages to the Java Client.

This works fine, but only on localhost. If im going to upload the script to my webserver, the Script cant find the Host of my PC.

Here is the Script ( Java side )

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 18181;
        ServerSocket listenSock = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        System.out.println("#######################################################");
        System.out.println("# RemoteCMD: Written by Ben Ammann -> ben-ammann.de   #");
        System.out.println("# Version: 1.3 | Updates on ben-ammann.de/remotecmd   #");
        System.out.println("# Support / News: ben-ammann.de/remotecmd/support     #");
        System.out.println("##########   Port 18181 created            ############");
        try {

            listenSock = new ServerSocket(port);

            while (true) {
                sock = listenSock.accept();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println("(" + dateFormat.format(date) + "): " + line);
                    int ret = 1;
                    try {
                        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = r.exec("cmd /c " + line);

                        try {
                            p.waitFor();

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        bw.write("Cant execute Command: null\n");
                        ret = 2;
                    }
                    if(ret == 1){
                        bw.write("Sucessfull\n");
                    }

                    bw.flush();
                }
                bw.close();
                br.close();
                sock.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the Php Script

```
if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $PORT = 18181;
    $HOST = "localhost";
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("error: could not create socket\n");
    $succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, $PORT) or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    socket_write($sock, $text . "\n", strlen($text) + 1) or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
    $reply = socket_read($sock, 10000, PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("error: failed to read from socket\n");
}
```

Comment: You have a Java ***server*** and a PHP ***client.*** Beyond the necessity to change `$HOST` to refer to a remote host rather than `"localhost"` it is difficult to understand what you're actually asking here.

Comment: I want to send a Message from the Php Script to the Destop Java Client.

Comment: Read up on HTTP and websockets, they will help you there. Also, you have the server-client concept reversed - the server is the long-running process with a well-known name, and the client connects to it.

Comment: You don't *have* a 'Desktop Java Client'. You have a Java *server.* Read what I wrote.